# In Jenkins pipeline, how can I make a choice parameter list editable?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following pipeline `Jenkinsfile` code that presents the user with a drop-down list.

```
properties ([
  disableConcurrentBuilds(),
  parameters ([
    choiceParam(name: "PICK_A_NUMBER",
                choices: [0, 1, 2, 3],
                description: "Simple choice")
  ])
])
```

How can I make it editable so the user can enter a different choice from the ones presented? Thanks!

Comment: As i learned,  all kinds of choice type parameter offered by Jenkins are only support to choose.

Comment: You could just have a second input parameter that takes in text and handle it in the pipeline.

Comment: @Chris Check out the [Editable Choice Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/editable-choice/), it implements exactly what you want

Comment: @MB That's what I have now, but I want to simplify it.

Comment: @NoamHelmer it of course worked. if you put your comment as an answer I'll accept it as the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an existing plugin called [Editable Choice Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/editable-choice/) which provides an editable choice parameter feature which is exactly what you are looking for, the plugin enables you to select a value from a list of choices, or alternatively you can input any custom value, even if does not appear in the choice list.

Usage is quite simple:

```groovy
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    editableChoice(
      name: 'PARAM1',
      choices: ['Apple', 'Grape', 'Orange'],
    )
  }
  stages {
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        echo "PARAM1=${params.PARAM1}"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

It also supports a default value option, an optional parameter to restrict the input to the choice list and a suggestions like filter config mechanism for displaying specific options.